# source command output lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to source a file containing several commands in a bash shell. How can I have the currently executed command printed on top of the commands output?

E.g. given this file `test.sh`

```
echo "hello"
echo "world"
```

the output of `source test.sh` should be:

```
echo "hello"
hello
echo "world"
world
```

Comment: Would the `set -v` option do what you want?

Comment: It depends on what you want.  `set -v` shows the commands *before* expansions, `set -x` shows them *after* expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `set -x` before `source test.sh`. This tells the shell to show the commands that are being executed before executing them.

Type `set +x` to undo it afterwards.